# Porque o max nem o min retorna o valor esperado?

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu estou precisando pegar o maior e o menor valor de um determinado campo para poder fazer um filtro, só que o SELECT MAX nem o MIN não funciona.

Como podem ver na imagem a baixo, eu preciso dessa quantidade de usuários

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nome da tabela: prt_license

```
SELECT MAX(users_licensed) FROM prt_license.
```

Quando eu executo essa Query, ele me retorna 50

```
SELECT MIN(users_licensed) FROM prt_license.
```

Quando eu executo essa Query, ele me retorna 100

O que eu posso fazer?

Comment: Qual o tipo da coluna?

Comment: pois é, agora que to reparando, ela é um varchar... ela é gerada automaticamente pelo sistema

Comment: Está correto o resultado. 5 é maior que 1

Comment: Só que tem campos com 400 usuarios, esse seria o maior

Comment: 4 fica entre 1 e 5, ordenando por strings seria 100, 3, 400, 50, 9, etc

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basicamente é erro de tipo.

- A string `50` começa com "5"
- A string `100` começa com "1"

O Min e o Max agem por ordem alfabética em strings.

Para testar, mude a *query* para isto:

```
SELECT MIN(0 + users_licensed) FROM prt_license
```

ou isto:

```
SELECT MAX(0 + users_licensed) FROM prt_license
```

Assim você estará forçando uma interpretação numérica. Mas isto é **só para testes**, idealmente você deve trabalhar com a coluna do tipo correto.

Outro bom teste (apenas como aprendizado) seria você colocar as colunas com um padding de zeros à esquerda, e ver que aí por "coincidência" as strings se comportam como números no quesito de ordenação:

```
010
050
100
120
```

etc.

### Para converter a coluna

**Faça backup** antes de alterações deste tipo. A *query* abaixo converte a coluna da tabela para o tipo correto, fazendo com que seu `SELECT` original funcione numericamente.

```
 ALTER TABLE prt_license MODIFY users_licensed INTEGER;
```

Depois da conversão, basta isto:

```
 SELECT MAX(users_licensed) FROM prt_license;
```

Comment: Não esperava por isso XD

Comment: Que solução engenhosa

Comment: Resolvido, valeu

Comment: @gabrielfalieri a solução eu postei agora no final, que é converter a tabela de fato. O SELECT foi só para testes.

Comment: Mudei pra integer... melhor mesmo

Answer (score 5):

Como as colunas são `varchar`, a ordenação é diferente de colunas numéricas.

Você pode fazer um cast na coluna pra trazer o resultado esperado.

Note que, idealmente, isso é só pra você ver que o `MIN` e `MAX` funcionam normalmente. O certo é trabalhar corretamente com os tipos das colunas.

```
SELECT MIN(CAST(users_licensed AS SIGNED)) FROM prt_license
```

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(users_licensed AS SIGNED)) FROM prt_license
```